# SwiftUI Keyboard Toolbar Conditional

Tags: ios, button, swiftui, toolbar

Not sure if this is a bug or if I'm doing something wrong but if I use:

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
        if isFocused == .zipCode {
            Text("Test")
        }
    }
}
```

When the field equaling zipCode is focused, my text shows up. However, if I do the same thing but use placement: .keyboard is does not, unless I also provide an additional view like this:

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
        if isFocused == .zipCode {
            Text("Test")
        }
        Text("Default")
    }
}
```

If I do that, I get the word Default on every keyboard and then on my zipCode field where the keyboard changes to a numberPad it shows Default Test.

I am trying to add a keyboard toolbar item only to the numberPad keyboard. I tried modifying the conditional to be TextField.keyboardType == .numberPad but you can't do that, nor could I get UIKeyboardType == .numberPad to work.

This form has multiple fields and I only want to add a button if the numberPad keyboard is shown. I do not want to add anything if other keyboard types are shown.

This is for SwiftUI (latest) with iOS 15.

Answer (score 1):

The .keyboard ToolBar is problematic in general. See: [Duplicate toolbar in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71279700/duplicate-toolbar-in-swiftui/71280848#71280848).
For your question this would work, but I suppose you want buttons...

```
    .toolbar {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
            Text(isFocused == .zipCode ? "ZIP" : "")
        }
    }
```

Comment: I can already do that as per my initial description. The issue is that all the keyboards get a toolbar and I do not want that. I only want the toolbar on a numberPad.

Comment: doesn't work in pure SwiftUI. You have to go for `UIViewRepresentable`